# Можно ли Visual Studio целиком установить на жесткий диск со 2 системой

Tags: visual-studio

Нет места на диске с основной системой для установки visual studio,  но есть место на диске со 2 системой, можно ли на диск со 2 системой поставить полностью visual studio?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Сформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), и [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019